# Trying to get around lack of CTE

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

I'm having some issues filtering the results from a longer query I have.

Suppose we have three columns, with some sample rows:

```
# column_1, column_2, column_3

'value 1', 'value 2', null
'value 1', 'value 2', '2'
'value 2', 'value 2', null
```

I'd like to select all rows but exclude those where column_3 is null and its column_1, column_2 values are associated with at least one non-null column_3 value.

A pain point is that I'm stuck with MySQL 5.7, and these rows are produced by a pretty text-lengthy subquery. If I had CTEs I could do:

```
WITH 
    cte1 AS (...)
SELECT *
FROM cte1 as a
WHERE
    column_3 IS NOT NULL
    OR NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM cte1 as b
        WHERE
            b.column_1 = a.column_1
            AND b.column_2 = a.column_2
            AND b.column_3 IS NOT NULL
    )
```

Is there some way I can do this without copy pasting the large subquery, given that I don't have access to CTEs?

Comment: I recommend you end the torture and upgrade to MySQL 8.0.

Comment: I'm learning on MySQL 8 and Postgres 13, but for this particular thing, it's not my choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With or without CTE's, you would need to copy paste the large subquery.  With would be:

```
with a as (subquery)
select *
from a
where ...
```

Without is even shorter:

```
select *
from (subquery) as a
where ...
```

Comment: I might've been unclear. I need to filter the results of that subquery, so I'd have to do SELECT * FROM (subquery) as a WHERE column_3 IS NOT NULL OR NOT EXISTS (subquery_based_query).

Comment: Which I can do, it just is quite the eyesore given the the length of that subquery.

Comment: Is the edit to the query in my original post invalid? It seems like it would be so much easier to read with CTEs, but it sounds like you're saying there would be no visual difference with or without CTEs?

Comment: ah, I see, you are using the same subquery again in a not exists criterion

Comment: Correct, I'm not sure there's a more terse way of writing that (if given CTEs).

Comment: without ctes, you could use a view or even a temporary table, but IMO that's messier and harder to understand than just copying the subquery.  I've had to copy a subquery something like 7 times once :)

Comment: Oh that sounds like torture haha. How did people live with this limitation in MySQL for so long? I'm just learning (and using MySQL 8 and Postgres 13 to learn), and having to use MySQL 5.7 for these things is pure torture.

Comment: do try mariadb too; there are some things mysql 8 has that mariadb 10.5 doesn't, and vice versa, but mariadb is regularly adding stuff and as far as I can tell, mysql is not

Comment: Will do once I learn about more in the two I'm currently going through!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have CTEs in MySQL 5.x another option is to create a view with the subquery.

Then you can just use the view several times in the main query. This is a poor replacement of a CTE and may experience several limitations and performance issues, but can do the trick, neverthelesss.

```
create view v1 as select ...;
```

Then, your main query remains pretty much unchanged:

```
SELECT *
FROM v1 as a
WHERE
    column_3 IS NOT NULL
    OR NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM v1 as b
        WHERE
            b.column_1 = a.column_1
            AND b.column_2 = a.column_2
            AND b.column_3 IS NOT NULL
    )
```